# Titanium Appcelerator strange bug

Tags: titanium-mobile

I've run into a really weird bug. I have the following code running in a function:

```
if (throwsThisRound % 3 == 0){
    debug('do it');
    throwsThisRound = 0;
    players[button.playerNum].throwsThisRound = 0;
    changeTurn();
};
```

This works perfectly fine. However, if I were to remove the debug function, which is just a function which runs `Ti.API.debug(param)`, nothing in the `if` statement runs. How can this happen? I have literally commented out the code, run my app, and uncommented the code and run again. I can reproduce this every time. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see very often is bugs like these. Add some line somewhere (or remove it) and all of a sudden in doesn't work anymore, without it actually changing.

The solution is very simple. Go to your `builds` folder, and remove the build content, but not the folder itself.

So remove the contents of these folders (depending on your deployment target):

```
/Titanium Workspace/Your Project Name/build/iphone/
/Titanium Workspace/Your Project Name/build/android/
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this next time. What I ended up doing was just running Clean, quitting and re-opening. I may just have had the app open for too long (days).